# Не приходит сообщение на почту

Tags: php, html, jquery, хостинг, sendmail

На странице есть две формы, данные с которой должны отправляться на почту, которая на хостинге.
При отправке выводиться что отправлено, но письма не приходят.

Вот такой код используется: 
**HTML**

```
<!-- Первая форма -->
<form class="send-form">
    <input type="text" value="" name="name"/>
    <input type="tel" value="" name="phone"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="---" name="mail"/>
    <input type="submit" value=""/>
</form>

<!-- Вторая форма -->
<form class="send-form">
    <input type="text" value="" name="name"/>
    <input type="tel" value="" name="phone"/>
    <input type="email" value="" name="mail"/>
    <input type="submit" value=""/>
</form>
```

**JQ**

```
$('.send-form').submit(function () {
    var formNm = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: 'mailsend.php', data: formNm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Ваша заявка отправлена');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
            alert('Увы, заявка не отправлена. \nПроверьте данные и повторите попытку');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**PHP** (`mailsend.php`)

```
<?php
    $back = "<p><a href=\"javascript: history.back()\">Вернуться назад</a></p>";
    $to  = "info@labevent.su";
    if(!empty($_POST['name']) and !empty($_POST['phone'])){
        $name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
        $phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
        $mail = trim(strip_tags($_POST['mail']));

        $subject = 'Новая заявка от '.$mail.'';

        $message = 'От: '.$name.'
        Почта: '.$mail.'
        Телефон: '.$phone.'';
        echo "Ваше сообщение отправленно!\n $back";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    } else echo "Для отправки сообщения заполните все поля! $back";

    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Bcc: birthday-archive@example.com\r\n";

    exit;
?>
```

Как это заставить работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас всё залито на хостинг, то думаю нужно написать в поддержку и попросить разрешение на отправку сообщений с хостинга, потому что по умолчанию у них эта функция заблокирована, у меня тоже так было, попробуйте решить с ними.